# Session Check in global.asax messing with filehandler.ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, global-asax

I have recently integrated all my session checks into the global.asax which works fine but since i've put it in there when my pages call my filehandler.ashx to get images I keep getting null reference errors for the session (but only when it calls that).

If I put a try/catch round it the images will load but obviously this isn't a good solution.

```
 void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context.Session["tid"] == null)  //Null Reference here
            {
```

Ideally, I'm looking for the event that fires on postback or first load that doesn't screw with the filehandler.  I guess if I can't I can always put it in the master_page init like before (is this bad practice?) because that seemed to work fine.  I just thought the global.asax would be a neater solution.

Any thoughts on what to try next?

Events i've tried so far..

```
Application_AcquireRequestState

Application_PostAcquireRequestState

Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute

Application_PreSendRequestContent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASHX requires session state to be inherited explicitly:

```
public class SomeCustomService : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Wow, just seen this, I will test it tonight and give an update.. was still looking to a solution for this thanks.

Comment: Checking back, After a bit more research I actually went with implementing IReadOnlySessionState but this worked too, definately got me on the right track and everything working nicely in global.asax.  Thanks alot :)